# Android canvas onTouch

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

Right, well what I have is three classes the 'Game', 'GridView' and 'TokenView' (although only the first and final classes are all I need help with :D ) and what I am trying to do here is get which column (getY) was touched in my 'TokenView' class using an onTouch method.

Game:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view);

    int[][] pos = new int[mColumn][mRow];

    /*Setting ball movement frame*/
    FrameLayout tokenFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.widget39);
    TokenView token = new TokenView(this);
    tokenFrame.addView(token);


    /*Setting drop area*/
    FrameLayout gridFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.widget41);
    GridView gridArea = new GridView(this);
    gridFrame.addView(gridArea);
}
public int getPlayer(){
    return player;
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){

    if(){
        //where I need help :D
    }

    return false;
}
```

TokenView:

```
public class TokenView extends View {

int Columns = 7;
public TokenView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Paint col = new Paint();
    col.setColor(Color.rgb(0,103,231));
    col.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    Paint red = new Paint();
    red.setAntiAlias(true); // smoothens edge
    red.setColor(Color.RED);
    red.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    Paint yellow = new Paint();
    yellow.setAntiAlias(true); // smoothens edge
    yellow.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    yellow.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    Rect myRect = new Rect();

    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), col);
    int columnWidth = canvas.getWidth() / 7;
    int rowHeight = (canvas.getHeight() / 17);
    int circleRadius = (canvas.getHeight() / 6) - 163;

    Game game = new Game();
    int player = game.getPlayer();


    for(int column = 0; column < Columns; column++)
    {
        if(player == 1){
            canvas.drawCircle((columnWidth*column)+55, (rowHeight)+10, circleRadius, red);
        }
        else if(player == 2){
            canvas.drawCircle((columnWidth*column)+55, (rowHeight)+10, circleRadius, yellow);
        }
        else if(player == 0){
            canvas.drawCircle((columnWidth*column)+55, (rowHeight*1)+10, circleRadius, col);
        }
    }
}
```

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: What type of class is Game class? And what do you want the program to do?

Comment: public class Game extends Activity

And I just want to get the column of the token touched within the canvas of the TokenView class so that I can then redraw the grid to place the token into the next available row of the column selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override the onTouch method in the TokenView class instead.
Canvas is just the place where things of the view are drawn.
You should write something like this in your TokenView class:

```
private Cell bufferCell;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
  Cell cell = getCell(event);
  if (cell != null)
  {
    switch (event.getAction())
    {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if (cell != bufferCell)
          bufferCell = cell;

        // DO STUFF HERE.
        // THE PLAYER HAS JUST TOUCHED A CELL.
        // invalidate();
        break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (cell != bufferCell)
        {
          bufferCell = cell;
          // Continue Pan
          // DO STUFF HERE
          // THE PLAYER'S FINGER IS ON A DIFFERENT CELL NOW, AND MOVING
          // invalidate();
        }
        break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // Commit Pan
        bufferCell = null;
        // DO STUFF HERE
        // THE PLAYER HAS TAKEN HIS FINGER OFF THE VIEW
        // invalidate();
        break;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

private Cell getCell(MotionEvent event)
{
  int motionX = (int) event.getX();
  int motionY = (int) event.getY();
  if (motionX > 0 && motionX < sizeOfGrid && motionY > 0
      && motionY < sizeOfGrid)
  {
    int rowIndex = motionY / currentSizeOfCell % rowCount;
    int columnIndex = motionX / currentSizeOfCell % columnCount;
    return cellArray[rowIndex][columnIndex];
  }
  return null;
}
```

Call `invalidate()` in order to redraw the view.
And **don't do** `Game game = new Game();` inside the `onDraw()` method of TokenView.
It will just keep on creating new Games while you draw stuff, and you will not get any expected behavior.

I used a `bufferCell` variable which will help reduce the amount of time your logic based methods will be called, because as the player moves his finger over the grid, the cell need not change. Only when it changes, calls to appropriate methods will be fired, if you follow the above mentioned code design.

Also read about as to how to create custom views in Android.
Main methods to override are `onDraw()`, `onSizeChanged()`, and `onMeasure()`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So I have modified your getCell method in order to meet my needs. And as long as I have done this correctly, If I were to add a console comment or a cat Log.d message within a switch-case for testing purposes, it would show up right?

Because so far I have just changed the numbers of rows and columns to meet my needs and the currentSizeOfCell to the circle radius. Is this right?

Comment: That you'll get to know when you'll test run it. CurrentSizeOfCell is the width and height of the cell though (each cell is a square in my logic), so you can set your currentSizeOfCell as twice the radius of each circle and in my opinion, it should then work.

Comment: On another subject :( sorry for hindering you like this, but. Would you know why, when I change the targetSdkVersion to 18 rather than the 19 that it was originally does the circles not draw?

Comment: So you say that the circles aren't being drawn when you changed your targetSdkVersion from 19 to 18? Do you even have Android SDK version 18 to build your project?

Comment: Ah right they are being draw, they just aren't showing because they are either too big or too small, and I would like it to fit and look the same across screen sizes from 2 to 7"

Comment: Well for that you need to scale your drawings according to the size of the phone. This requires a little bit of Mathematics. ;)